# How to fix the code to go for different pages according to radio button selected using single form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to go to different templates(page) whatever is selected(radio button) from a single form. I want to include just one button in my form.

Here as if someone selects `template1` I will to page template1.php.
If I select `template2` I will go to template2.php.

I have saved the below code as form.php

```
<form method="POST" action=
                          "<?php if(($rb = $_POST('template'))=='1'){?>
                                          template1.php 
                           <?php } 
                            if(($rb = $_POST('template'))=='2'){?>
                                          template2.php 
                            <?php } ?>"
                            enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
         <label>First Name: </label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname">
         <label>Last Name: </label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="template">Template 1
         <input type="radio" value="2" name="template">Template 2
         <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>      

  </form>
```

Comment: I guess you need to use javascript

Comment: Can you please help me out in this. I am new to javascript.

Comment: Do you want the button or skip the button?

Comment: I mean if you select a radio button it will go directly to the page

Comment: I need a button too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript for this instead. PHP is a server-side language, which means that you have to submit the form to the server before PHP knows which option you selected. JavaScript can deal with this right when you change it instead, as it is a client-side language.

Create an event-listener for a click on the input with the name of `template`. Then toggle the action accordingly to that.

```js
$("input[name=template]").on("click", function() {
  var action = "";
  switch($(this).val()) {
    case "1":
      action = 'template1.php';
      break;
    case "2":
      action = 'template2.php';
      break;
  }
  $(this).parent("form").prop("action", action);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
         <label>First Name: </label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname">
         <label>Last Name: </label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname">
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="template">Template 1
         <input type="radio" value="2" name="template">Template 2
         <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>      

  </form>
```