# How to make drop down menu reflect the form action in PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html

I want to change the form action based on the input of the drop down menu in the html.

For example - 
When I submit the form and select Volvo then the form should redirect all the input or action to the volvo.php

```
<form action= "*Depending on the input of the drop down menu*">
  <select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat" selected>Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should rethink your approach. This logic is better dealt with after the form has been submitted in a cars.php file and then dependant on the option selected direct to the appropriate file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to direct everything to a single script and then just `IF $_POST['cars'] == 'volvo'){` or write a switch `switch ($_POST['cars']) { case: 'volvo'`

Comment: You can achieve it by using JavaScript (I posted a similar answer earlier today https://stackoverflow.com/a/56035972/4535200), but you're probably better off handling it server-side based on the selected option.

Comment: I agree, this idea doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you really going to have a separate PHP script for every make of car? Why? What is different in each of those scripts, exactly? Instead, submit to the same script every time, have that script read that value submitted, and then decide what to do with that information. That way if you add more makes of cars you don't need to keep adding scripts.

Comment: you can use ajax for that i think. when you select the car and submit ajax, in the other file you get the if($cars = X)[include  this file]else[include this other file]..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is definitely not the preferred way of doing this - the best way would be to have only one php file where you would check the value and act accordingly - here goes how to achieve what you asked for (using jQuery as an example):

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <select id="cars" name="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat" selected>Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $("#submitButton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#MyForm').attr('action', $('#cars').val()+".php").submit();

    });
</script>
```